# Is there a demand for Touchscreen-based UIs for Car/Mobile PC Platforms?

Tags: java, user-interface, qt, media-player, touchscreen

Does anyone know if there's a very big demand for a touchscreen-based keyboard less UI for Car, Navigation, or Mobile devices?

I know that Android is a very big, very popular platform.  So is Cocoa Touch.

What I'd like to envision is using a Java UI with something like Qt that can be applied to a touchscreen.  I would initially use Android, but I don't have as much control with that.  I'd like to see a roll-your-own, highly customized Linux kernel that's only used for media playback and the like.

It could even be applied to a set-top box for a TV, or a media player box like a portable Internet Radio with a 3G/4G network card.

I'd be interested in heading up the project, but would like to know if any interest actually exists for this type of project.  It would, of course, be Open Source.

Comment: I voted to close as "too localized", because the answers will only be relevant for a very short period of time. Six months from now, a year from now and five  years from now the answers will be completely different.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to say "not much".  Those devices are usually highly customized, so the entire UI is application specific.  Now, the core OS may be shared, but as far as the UI goes, not so much.